# SyntaxError: The requested module 'vue-demi' does not provide an export named 'hasInjectionContext' while running tests with Pinia in Vitest

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, vite, vitest, nuxt3

I am trying to run tests with Pinia in Vitest, but I am encountering the following error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'vue-demi' does not provide an export named 'hasInjectionContext'
```

The error seems to be related to an issue with the 'vue-demi' module, which is a dependency of Vue Test Utils. Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Here are the relevant packages listed in my package.json file:

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.12",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.2",
    "@graphql-tools/merge": "^8.3.11",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^9.0.9",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^0.29.8",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.2",
    "cli-color": "^2.0.3",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "happy-dom": "^8.9.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.0.0",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.1.7",
    "rollup": "^3.20.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "vite": "^3.2.5",
    "vitest": "^0.29.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "es5-ext": "^0.10.62",
    "pinia": "^2.1.3",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "v-lazy-image": "^2.1.1",
    "vue3-datepicker": "^0.3.4"
  }
```

[image: Error snapshot]

Comment: " which is a dependency of Vue Test Utils" - it's not, at least not directly. It's unknown what happens on your end. Search for vue-demi in node_modules, there should be only one that Pinia uses

Answer (score 0):

downgrade pinia to 2.0.x and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

had that error too, my approach were:

1. Reinstall `node_modules` and rerun the tests
2. If that doesn't work, upgrading node.js (not sure which node.js version you have, but I upgraded it to 16.20.0), and all tests work as normal

Hopefully that helps